# is there a better way to invalidate the redis cache used in asp.net mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, stackexchange.redis

I have a asp.net mvc 5 application with entity framework 6.1.

For caching i have used redis cache in my application. that works fine for me all add update and remove items with key are working.

what i am expecting is that whenever a request comes for data it will first check cache then go towards the db if data is not found in cache and then populate cache accordingly for the subsequent requests. I have implemented Generic repository pattern with data storage and caching strategies.

The issue i am facing is this:

- once the data is cached then how i come to know that any updates, delete or add operation is done to the data then sync those data changes with redis cache
- how should i store data into redis database for different tables as each table may have data with same primary key values. then while fetching record from redis how do i come to know that value with key 1 is from table A, or table B.

Below i have shown the code for my repository class with injectable redis cache. what i want for methods like GetList, firstOrDefault fisrt the data is served from cache then from my db if needed

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<TEntity> :IBasicOperations<TEntity> 
where TEntity : class
{

    protected IDataStoreStrategy<TEntity> _dataStoreStrategy;    // Data Storage Strategy e.g, SQL SERVER
    protected ICachingStrategy _cachingStrategy;    // Caching Strategy e.g, Redis
    public GenericRepository(IDataStorageContext db, ICachingStrategy cache)
    {
        _cachingStrategy = cache;
        this._dataStoreStrategy = new BaseActions<TEntity>(db);
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
        this._dataStoreStrategy.Add(entity, SaveChanges);
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(TEntity entity, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
       await this._dataStoreStrategy.AddAsync(entity, SaveChanges);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
        this._dataStoreStrategy.AddRange(entities, SaveChanges);
    }

    public async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
       await this._dataStoreStrategy.AddRangeAsync(entities, SaveChanges);
    }

    public TEntity FindById(object Id)
    {
       return this._dataStoreStrategy.FindById(Id);
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> FindByIdAsync(object Id)
    {
       return await _dataStoreStrategy.FindByIdAsync(Id);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> FindWithCondition(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        return this._dataStoreStrategy.FindWithCondition(filter,orderBy,includeProperties);
    }

    public TEntity First(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {

        return this._dataStoreStrategy.First(where);

    }

    public Task<TEntity> FirstAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        return this._dataStoreStrategy.FirstAsync(where);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetList()
    {
        return this._dataStoreStrategy.GetList();
    }

    //public T Last(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    //{
    //    return this._dataStoreStrategy.Last(where);
    //}

    public void Remove(TEntity entity, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
        this._dataStoreStrategy.Remove(entity, SaveChanges);
    }

    public async Task RemoveAsync(TEntity entity, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
       await this.RemoveAsync(entity,SaveChanges);
    }

    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
        this._dataStoreStrategy.RemoveRange(entities, SaveChanges);
    }

    public async Task RemoveRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
       await this._dataStoreStrategy.RemoveRangeAsync(entities, SaveChanges);
    }

    public void Save()
    {

        this._dataStoreStrategy.Save();
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync()
    {
       await this._dataStoreStrategy.SaveAsync();
    }

    public TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
       return this._dataStoreStrategy.Single(where);
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> SingleAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        return await this._dataStoreStrategy.SingleAsync(where);
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
        this._dataStoreStrategy.Update(entity, SaveChanges);
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(TEntity entity, bool SaveChanges = true)
    {
      await  this._dataStoreStrategy.UpdateAsync(entity, SaveChanges);
    }
    internal CaliberMatrixEntities ctx { get { return _dataStoreStrategy.ctx as CaliberMatrixEntities; } }
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll() { return null; }
    public virtual TEntity Get(long id) { return null; }
    public virtual void Delete(long id) { }
    public virtual void Change(TEntity t, Guid by) { }
    public virtual void Add(TEntity t, Guid by) { }
    public virtual void AddRange(List<TEntity> t) { }
    public virtual void DeleteRange(List<int> t) { }
}
```

Comment: _"what i want for methods like GetList, firstOrDefault fisrt the data is served from cache then from my db if needed"_ - so for single items you could base the cache key on the type and ID of the entity, and when it gets updated remove the key (and hence value) from the cache. Then the next time you retrieve the entity, it's not in the cache, so you get it from the DB and then cache it ..? For caching lists, though, you would need something more complicated: if you cached a list of items and one of them changes, what do you want to do? ...

Comment: ...  Invalidate the whole list and get it again? Get the list, update the changed records, and recache the list? What problem are you solving here by using caching?

Comment: yes i did the same i create a cache key on the type and ID of the entity. but i am confused how will i dealt with list of entities in a serialized manner. like i query from data source "db.mytable.ToList()" it will return Ienumerable<> and then how i add it into my redis cache. so that for againt excution of the GetList() method data will be fetched from redis

Comment: actually i have ovverride the savechanges method of my context so that i didnt add to much logic to check which entities are modified and updated and deleted. then from overridden savechanges() method i want to do cache invalidation